# Android SDK => Mint 71.2 64

Tags: java, android

Running invocation script `./studio.sh` to invoke SDK IDE produces error msg:

> JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath. Please insure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

Lots of solutions have been posted, but none of them work for me.  My most recent attempt involved editing `/etc/profile` by adding:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Any comments or ideas?

Thanks to everyone for their patience and consideration - JDA

Comment: what do you get if you type `java -version` ? Have you verified that the JAVA_HOME path is correct ?

Comment: Solved problem by adding ppa:webupd8team/java and downloaded a java installer..  java -version and javac -version both provide the expected information - also Android Studio operates properly.  My larger nagging issue is that I'm mystified by the process which creates the environment(s) and the files and scripts involved.  Shell variables vs environment variables.  interactive scripts. login scripts. interactive login scripts. etc. etc.  Finding bits and pieces and trying to fit it all together in a coherent way. But my initial problem is solved.  Many thanks Manos.    jda8818